# Can sphinx be used over cassandra?

Tags: full-text-search, distributed, sphinx, nosql, cassandra

I am planning to build a cassandra store system and also I need a full-text(Chinese) system too. Can sphinx be used on cassandra? (sphinx supports xml format but I am not going to use it, cause it is slow and much of time are spent on xml parsing). Or you can share your experiences if you have ever built a full-text searching system over cassandra. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at [Lucandra](http://github.com/tjake/Lucandra) (Lucandra = [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) + [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) )

Comment: what's its advantages over sphinx? I heard that sphinx had a good performance

Comment: Both Solr and Sphinx has very good performance. Here is one comparison http://beerpla.net/2009/09/03/comparison-between-solr-and-sphinx-search-servers-solr-vs-sphinx-fight/ (looks a bit biased).

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way to build sphinx index except of using xml pipe as of now

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would also recommend using Solandra (ex. Lucandra), which is Solr implementation which  uses Cassandra as backend storage. Solandra server node runs both Solr and Cassandra on the same JVM.

One strong points with Solandra over pure Solr or Sphinx is implicit distributed searches over cluster. I have not heard that Sphinx would have Cassandra backend.

Comment: One less attractive feature for my use with Solandra is that it is Java based, where Sphinx runs without JVM, Sphinx has also better integration with SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do initial "feed" with XML, then you could use "live" indexing - using SphinxQL on Sphinx "MySQL" port (3307 I believe).

We do than on very large 200M MySQL table.